# ¿Como hago que una función con una variable booleana me devuelva un 1 o un 0 en java?

Tags: java, condiciones, booleano

El programa que tengo que hacer en java utilizando if es este:

```
 FUNCION delta (Booleano p) 
   POST: Si p es cierto devuelve 1 y si es falso devuelve 0
   POST: p   --> 1
         eoc --> 0
```

Mi programa compila pero me devuelve exactamente lo contrario a lo que le pido:

```
class Seleccion {
 static int delta (boolean p){
     if(p=true)
       return 1;
     else 
       return 0;
   }
public static void main(String [] args){
  System.out.println (+delta (true));  
}
 }
```

Aquí me devolvería un 0. Estoy aprendiendo a programar, ¿alguien me ayuda con esto?

Answer (score 1):

La comparación se hace con el doble igual `==`

```
static int delta (boolean p){
         //if(p=true)  el error aquí, para comparar se usa el doble igual ==
         if(p == true)
           return 1;
         else 
           return 0;
       }
```

Además puedes simplificar la función usando el operador ternario `?:` así:

```
static int delta (boolean p){
     return p ? 1 : 0;
   }
```

Comment: de hehco el `== true` no es neceario en lo absoluto xD

Answer (score 1):

Coincido con Lobos, capaz la segunda forma con el operador Ternario sea más complicada de ver en tu caso si estás comenzado con la programación.
Si el operador ternario lo queres ver más fácil, el ? es un if y los 2 puntos un else.

También tené en consideración que un if no es necesidad de agregar un comparador

```
if(p == true)
```

ya que la estructura es un comparador natural en sí para booleanos verdaderos. Es completamente válido escribirlo como

```
if(p)
```

entonces el código quedaría

```
public class Seleccion {
static int delta (boolean p){
         if(p)
           return 1;
         else 
           return 0;
       }
public static void main(String [] args){
  System.out.println (delta (true));  
}
 }
```

O como escriben algunos  desarrolladores Sr..

```
public class Seleccion {
static int delta (boolean p){if(p)return 1;else return 0; }
public static void main(String [] args){
  System.out.println (delta (true));  
}
 }
```

Un saludo!